# Deserialize JSON with nested lists from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dotnet-httpclient, json-deserialization

I've already tried some solutions described on Stackoverflow (e.g. [Best way to deserialize a nested list in a json - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877524/best-way-to-deserialize-a-nested-list-in-a-json-c-sharp)).

I have already tried this, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe I have made a mistake somewhere.

This is my code to do an HTTP request:

```cs
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, someData);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

AllChapters allChapters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllChapters>(responseString);
```

But when I run my code, `allChapters` is always empty (null) even if there is data inside `responseString`. Do any of you have a solution for this? I might have missed something, but I don't know what exactly.

And this is what my `responseString` looks like:

```json
{
  "AllChapters": [
    {
      "ChapterIndex": 1,
      "ChapterParagraphs": [
        {
          "ParagraphIndex": 1,
          "Text": "SomeText"
        }
      ],
      "Title": "First Chapter"
    },
    {
      "ChapterIndex": 2,
      "ChapterParagraphs": [
        {
          "ParagraphIndex": 1,
          "Text": "SomeText"
        },
        {
          "ParagraphIndex": 2,
          "Text": "SomeText"
        }
      ],
      "Title": "Second Chapter"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've created three classes to store the data:

***AllChapters***

```cs
public class AllChapters
{
    public List<OneChapter> OneChapter { get; set; }
}
```

***OneChapter***

```
public class OneChapter
{
    public int ChapterIndex { get; set; }

    public List<ChapterParagraph> ChapterParagraphs { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public OneChapter()
    {
        ChapterIndex = 0;
        ChapterParagraphs = new List<ChapterParagraph>;
        Title = string.empty;
    }
}
```

***ChapterParagraph***

```cs
public class ChapterParagraph
{
    public int ParagraphIndex { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ParagraphScore()
    {
        ParagraphIndex = 0;
        Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON response doesn't match with your `AllChapters` class. In your root class, it consists of the `AllChapters` property:

With `JsonPropertyName` attribute as corrected by @Ibram,

```cs
public class AllChapters
{
    [JsonPropertyName("AllChapters")]
    public List<OneChapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}
```

or renaming the root class:

```cs
public class ReadingMaterial
{
    public List<OneChapter> AllChapters { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
ReadingMaterial readingMaterial = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadingMaterial>(responseString);
```

Comment: Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type, he can annotate it with `[JsonPropertyName("AllChapters")]`

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. I actually had to rename "AllChapters" in my json, because I couldn't name the property inside `AllChapters` class the same as the class name. The property must have a different name than the class name.

Comment: Yes, apologize for mis-looking it. Thanks @Ibram for the correction. Either renaming the property name or the class name to ensure no conflicting.